# could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type - Spark

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark

Im new to Scala and spark and could do with some help regarding the above error.
Here is a snippet of my code that is causing issues:

```
case class Session (user_id: String, creation_date: BigInt, offline: Boolean)
case class User (user_id: String, app_id: Int, vendor_code: String, app_version: String)

val users = sc.cassandraTable[User]("leech_seed", "user").select("user_id", "app_id", "vendor_code", "app_version").where("last_active >=" + (timestamp - 86400000))
val sessions = sc.cassandraTable[Session]("leech_seed", "session").select("user_id", "creation_date", "offline").where("creation_date < " + timestamp + " AND creation_date >=" + (timestamp - 86400000))
```

when i use this code in the spark shell it works fine but when i am trying to build a jar with sbt i get the following error `could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.reader.RowReaderFactory[User]`

This has been doing my head in for longer than id like to admit so any help/insight would be greatly appreciated.

**Note:** I am using the [datastax cassandra connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/) for spark

Comment: Which spark-cassandra connector are you using?

Comment: im using the scala 2.10 connectror

Comment: I should also have asked with which version of Cassandra?

Comment: its cassandra 2.1.9 but i dont think that can be related as its a compile time error not a run time one

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the latest version of the 2.10 connector? (2.10 version 1.4.0-M3)

Comment: spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-1.5.0-M1-SNAPSHOT.jar, it was the version i got off of giothub, ill have a look into updating it to see if it helps any

Comment: That's this months update - I'm asking as I have had similar errors from using certain Spark versions with different connector versions. At the moment I am using Spark 1.4.1 with 2.10-1.4.0-M3 with no problems.

Comment: okay, so firstly im using the above file on my test server but i just checked my build.sbt file and that was using 1.0.4 so not all that surprising i was having issues! i am now getting the error `No RowReaderFactory can be found for this type` but its progress

Comment: Yes thats a standard one - your case classes need to be declared outside of your main method

Comment: aaand im compiled, thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your spark-cassandra connector version is up-to-date with the version of Spark you are using. I have encountered these issues using connector versions older than 2.10-1.4.0-M3 with Spark 1.4.1.

Also ensure that your case classes are defined outside of your main method - else you will encounter `No RowReaderFactory can be found for this type`or similar.